# Problem filter aggregated data in (SAPUI5) SmartChart with CDS-Views

Tags: sapui5, cds

I have built a Freestyle SAPUI5 app with a SmartFilterBar and SmartCharts (Donut). These smart controls consume CDS views and the associated annotations. The display of the data in the donut charts works already.

[image: SmartFilterBar and SmartCharts in SAPUI5 App]

[image: XML-View]

However, I am having trouble filtering the data in the donut chart. In the first chart, I can only filter by "contract type". This field is also used in the CDS view. How can I make it possible to filter by "business entity" (benocn) and "company code" (bukrs)?  By making a "count" on "objnr" in the view ZC_RE_CN_LOCKED, I can't include the fields business entity, company code and contract number in the select, otherwise the counting of the entries doesn't fit anymore.
Does anyone possibly have an idea how to filter aggregating values?

[image: CDS-View - Mastersearch - "ZC_RE_DASBOARD"]

[image: CDS-View - 1. Donut Chart - "ZC_RE_CN_LOCKED"]

[image: CDS-View - Select contracts]

I have tried the following instead of "@DefaultAggregation:#COUNT_DISTINCT", unfortunately without success:

```
@Aggregation.default: #COUNT_DISTINCT
@Aggregation.referenceElement: ['objnr']
cast( 1 as abap.int4 ) as sum_contracts
```